# Creating random array from JSON data

Tags: php, json

I have a function in which I want to pass to it an array of random numbers from 0 to 3, which would then correlate to then number of JSON objects I have stored.  What I ultimately want to do is create an array in which these four JSON objects used to fill a 60 element array, in a random order.  My problem so far is that the json_decode is returning null, so I can't proceed any further.  I ran json_last_error and it returned 4, which I believe points to a syntax error, but I can't figure it out.  Any ideas?

my function:

```
public function createSpatialKey($random_array){

    $test = array();
    $image_array = file_get_contents('files/memory_key.json');

    $image_array = json_decode($image_array, true);
    print_r($image_array); 

    $type = json_last_error();

    echo $type;

    foreach($random_array as $question){
      array_push($test, $image_array[$question]);
    } 

    return $test;
}
```

My JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "image": "<div id='spatial_location1'>1</div>",
    "answer": 1,
    "stimulus_id": 1,
  },
  {
    "image": "<div id='spatial_location2'>2</div>",
    "answer": 2,
    "stimulus_id": 2,
  },
  etc... 
]
```

Comment: There is an extra comma after the "stimulus_id" entry that renders the JSON invalid.

Comment: I can't believe I stared at this for an hour, and I completely missed that.  Thank you for your sharp eyes!

Comment: If you put it as an answer, I will check it as so.

Comment: Great that solved it! I added my answer below, thanks for accepting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra comma after the "stimulus_id" entry that renders the JSON invalid. And I know what you are talking about :-)